# Что есть в Java, чего нет в C#?

Tags: c#, android, java, синтаксис

Решил попробовать писать под андроид и столкнулся с необходимостью писать на Java. До этого писал больше на C#. Языки похожие во многом, но есть и отличия. И так как пока я C# знаю лучше Java, то так получается, что я пользуюсь только теми возможностями синтаксиса Java, которые знаю по C#. В общем, сейчас для меня java превратился в "урезаный C#", потому что каких-то чисто джавовских "фишек" я не знаю, а некоторых возможностей из C# в этом языке нет. Ну, например, в Java нет оператора `??`, нет linq, нет свойств, нет атрибутов.

Так вот сам вопрос: а что есть в Java, чего нет в C#? Именно из синтаксиса, различных удобностей и синтаксического сахара.

Comment: А документацию почитать по яве? :-)

Comment: @Чад, ну действительно, зачем человеку быстро осваивать те области, с которыми он не знаком, пусть лучше еще раз почитает с самого начала про то, что такое объекты, методы и свойства.

Comment: @Etki, есть оглавление, можно идти по нему и, что не понятно, уточнять уже в документации. :-)

Comment: @Чад, а еще есть один такой сайт, где девелоперы помогают друг другу, показывая шоткаты, чтобы один девелопер мог не тратить слишком времени на чересчур подробное изучение вопроса, которое ему в данный момент не требуется.

В последнее время, конечно, вопросы такие, что в большинстве случаев остается апеллировать только к документации, но посылать туда людей просто так с вопросами, которые напрямую в доках не рассмотрены, - это некрасиво.

Comment: @Etki, возможно, Вы и правы, хотя относительно этого вопроса моё мнение не изменится - тематика поднята даже в википедии, как написал @KoVadim, и это надо быть очень ленивым, чтобы не заглянуть хотя бы туда, прежде чем задавать такой вопрос. Я изменю своё мнение, только после того как увижу тут ответ самого автора, основанный на его опыте впитывания информации и систематизированный для Сети Знаний. Иначе - это очередной шлако вопрос, который уменьшает качество Сети Знаний.

Comment: @Чад, IMHO на самом деле вопрос не так уж и плох.

А вот отсылка к сторонним источникам без хотя бы краткого ответа по сути и уменьшает качество Сети Знаний.

Я понимаю, что частенько нам просто лень отвечать, но если постоянное "отфутболивание" продолжится, то скоро вопросы (причем любого качества) задавать станет вообще некому...

Comment: @Чад, статью из вики я прочел задолго до того, как задать вопрос. Мой вопрос не про отличия C# и Java, а про то, что есть в java, но нет в шарпе именно на счет синтаксиса. Ответа на него статья из вики не содержит. Там я увидел много примеров того, что есть в шарпе, но нет в джаве или просто про отличия между языками, но не про то, что есть в java, но нет в C#. Увидел только пару строк про конструкцию  strictfp.

Ваш отсыл к документации, конечно, очень полезен, но этим я займусь на досуге. Тут я ожидал хотя бы пару конкретных примеров.

Comment: <Немного нытья>
  
Почему то на stackoverflow если задать вопрос то на него просто ответят. Здесь же тебя пошлют в документацию, назовут лентяем и обвинят во всех грехах. 

>Иначе - это очередной шлако вопрос, который уменьшает качество сети знаний

ответы типа "читай документацию" уменьшают ее качество еще больше чем вопросы от наивных новичков. 

</Немного нытья>

Comment: @JuniorTwo, повышайте качество вопросов.

Если бы Вы сразу сослались в вопросе на прочитанную в вике статью, то нападок не было бы вообще (как, возможно, и ответов).

Кстати, Вы бы отредактировали вопрос, да и выделили бы, что Вас прежде всего интересуют отличия именно в языке (тексте, который обрабатывает компилятор), а не в стандартных библиотеках. 

(Хотя, может быть, для шарпа и явы (в отличие, скажем, от Си) язык без библиотек вообще не стоит рассматривать?)

Comment: @avp, я еще при создании вопроса указал, что меня интересует то, что есть в java, но нет в C# в плане синтаксиса. А указывать, что и где я прочитал до этого, было бы странно. Никто же в других вопросах этого не делает. Я же просто задаю вопрос и просто хочу получить на него ответ. Если вопрос по-вашему плох, то поставьте минус или пройдите мимо. Вспомните тот же stackoverflow. Там просто задают вопросы и получают ответы, а не занимаются нравоучениями про лень и не требуют указать список прочитанных источников, прежде чем задать вопрос.

Comment: @JuniorTwo, если Вы грамотно зададите вопрос, и что конкретно Вы делаете и для чего используете и хотите использовать C# и Java, я с удовольствием поделюсь с Вами своим опытом использования того и другого. Потому что вопрос - чего нету в Java а есть в C# по синтаксису - полноценный ответ даёт документация. Тут нет ничего сокрального или полученного в следствии опыта. А вот "трюки" и "особенности реализации" - это я так понимаю что Вас интересует,но это как спросить - а какие кнопки есть в бмв а каких нет мерседесе-я хочу ездить на бмв как на мерседесе, а не на огрызке мерседеса :-)

Comment: @avp, тут дело не в лени. Как Вы правильно заметили - каков вопрос, таков ответ.

Comment: @Чад, что не так в вопросе "про какие вещи типа linq в c# мне нужно знать заранее?"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Смотрите.

В основном по фичам в данный момент C# идёт впереди Java, Java находится в позиции догоняющего. Однако есть несколько фич, которые есть в Java и нет в C# и которые при правильном использовании могут облегчить жизнь программисту.

1) Легковесные (анонимные) производные классы.

Пример:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { // это анонимный производный класс!
        @override
        public void run() {
            // do some work
        }
    }).start();
```

В C# надо было бы объявить производный класс явно. Аналогичная, но не равносильная фича C# — анонимные *методы*, то есть лямбды.

2) Нестатические внутренние классы. В C# внутренние классы лишь логически находятся «внутри» и не имеют доступа к instance-переменным. В Java внутренние классы более богаты.

3) `enum`'ы. В C# они такие же, как в C++, и являются по существу именованными константами целочисленного типа. В Java `enum`'ы есть константы объектного типа, гораздо более богатые семантически.

4) checked exceptions. Вы можете объявлять как часть сигнатуры метода исключения, которые бросаются этим методом. В C# такой возможности нету. (Хотя разработчики C# считают, что эта фича не нужна [и даже вредна](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html), тем не менее по факту это фича, которая есть в Java и нет в C#.)

5) `final`-параметры. В C# `const` могут лишь переменные и поля, в Java можно параметр объявить как `final`, и при попытке его изменить компилятор наругается на вас.

6) [`SoftReference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299702/276994) представляет собой «более сильную» версию `WeakReference` (которые тоже есть в Java): объекты, референсируемые ими, не удаляются, пока памяти хватает, даже если другие объекты уничтожаются в процессе сборки мусора.

7) У Java есть симпатичные [помеченные блоки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), которые позволяют выйти из *любого* количества циклов за раз (`break`) или пропустить итерацию во внешнем цикле (`continue`). Также `break <label>;` может выйти из *любого* блока, не только цикла (что делает его равносильным `goto`).

8) В Java вы можете ловить в одном `catch` несколько исключений: `catch (IOException | SQLException ex)`. C# такое не умеет.

---

С выходом новой версии Java 8 добавилось ещё одно расхождение:

9) У Java есть очень полезная фича: [default interface implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), с помощью которой можно устраивать подобие mixin'ов: написать код, который можно добавить к *любому* классу, с возможностью перегрузки.

У C# похожее поведение можно смоделировать при помощи extension-методов (которых в Java как раз нет) и маркерных интерфейсов, но вы не сможете *полиморфно* перегрузить метод в конкретном классе, только перекрыть. В результате если у вас есть указатель на базовый класс, вызов в случае C# приведёт к вызову метода для базового класса.

Comment: Тут нужно заметить: 1. Производные классы — на 99% костыль из-за (бывшего) отсутствия лямбд. 2. Доступ к this реализуется в две строчки. 3. А-ля джавовые enum'ы никто не мешает создавать, просто они никому не нужны. 4. Проверяемые исключения давно признаны ошибкой. 5. Абсолютно ненужная вещь, которой никто не пользуется. 6. Малополезная вещь, учитывая понятие "память кончается". 7. Для всего есть полноценный goto.

Comment: Плюсую за проверяемые исключения! Чхал я на то, кто их признает ошибкой, по мне - великолепная фича, без них в C# с огромным трудом слежу за исключениями!

Comment: Smart enum: http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/16/producing-combinations-part-two/      http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/10/23/violating-the-smart-enum-pattern-in-c/      http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2015/03/private-constructor-in-abstract-base.html

Comment: В 8-й Java так же появились лямбды.
`Thread thread = new Thread(()->{System.out.println("Привет!");});`
`root.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent e)->{System.out.println("Привет!");});`
`root.setOnMousePressed((e)->{System.out.println("Привет!");});` В последнем варианте тип подбирается в зависимости от контекста (Без нашей помощи) и работает пример как и в случае с указанным типом для e.

Comment: @DimXenon: Это да, но вопрос не об этом, вопрос о том, что есть в Java и нет в C#. Лямбды в C# есть.

Comment: @Squidward, VladD SoftReference столь же полезны, как и MemoryCache. И используются для того же самого.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Насколько я вижу, SoftReference — это кэширование "для ленивых" с ограниченным функционалом, трудно предсказуемым временем жизни, сомнительными последствиями на производительности и мутной спецификацией ("зависит от реализации" — и таки действительно зависит).

Comment: @Squidward я бы не сказал, что оно "для ленивых" - скорее напротив, ленивый пожелает использовать MemoryCache вместо реализации того же самого на SoftReference.

Comment: Вот кстати default interface implementation — это реально мегафича, потому что интерфейсы перестают быть ночным кошмаром для обратной совместимости. Теперь интерфейсы могут насладиться бонусами абстрактных классов, при этом продолжая поддерживать множественную реализацию. Другими словами, костыли вокруг отсутствия множественного наследования стали менее костыльными.

Answer (score 8):

Вот теперь ведь никто мимо не пройдёт.

> Ну, например, в Java нет
> оператора ??

Зато есть обычный {o == null ? no : o}, это не урезание, а лишь отсутствие сахара. Функционально не обедняет.

> нет linq

Да, linq нет, но для работы с коллекциями можно библиотечку подыскать вроде Google Guava, если в самом деле так нужно. Для работы с результатами запросов из бд тоже можно решить проблему. На мой взгляд, решения делать через синтаксис языка лучше, чем liq, который работает примерно так: парсим один синтаксис, получаем другой, другой исполняем...

> нет свойств

Да, в java принято самому писать `get*`  и `set*` методы. Это даже в спецификации java bean описано. (Ну, если вспомить C#, он просто делает методы `get_*`, `set_*` за кулисами). В настоящий момент нет необходимости всё подряд через геттеры получать... можно и поля аннотировать.

> нет атрибутов

Но есть аннотации.

Лично я считаю, .Net и Java - аналогичные технологии, призванные решать по большому счёту одни и те же задачи. Есть, конечно, свои особенности... и простое правило: пишешь только под Windows - используй .Net. Нет, Java лучше.

Comment: HOLYWAR!!! :-)

Comment: @JuniorTwo Так я об этом и говорю - ничего.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, если в C# есть много чего из того, чего нет в java, а в java нет ничего такого, чего нет в c#, то тогда у меня напрашивается глупый вывод, что c# более богатый и удобный язык. Но это ведь, наверное, не так.

Comment: @JuniorTwo 

>если в C# есть много чего из того, чего нет в java 

так я не говорил)

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, ну, это и правда так - linq, ??, перегрузка операторов, беззнаковые типы, события, свойства, делегаты, индексаторы, структуры, async/await. Всего этого в java, насколько знаю, нет (хотя и может быть реализовано засчет дополнительных средств). Так вот что есть наоборот в java, но нет в C#?

Comment: @JuniorTwo обычно всяких дополнений и различных подходов всем хватает.
Не встречал задачу, для которой мне бы пришлось писать под .net.

Ну и да, в java любят дополнения, разные библиотечки, сравнивать производительность и выбирать.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov: Напишите, как эмулировать async/await в Java, а? И как без LINQ написать вот такой однострочник:

    File.WriteAllLines("filtered.txt",
        File.ReadLines("input.txt).Where(s => !s.StartsWith("#")));

Comment: Ну ёлки в java это всё в google делается:

*Java Equivalent async/await*, потом выбираем библиотечку для конкуренции, и всё.

Однострочник не пример, неверно строками мерить, но для удобной работы с коллекциями куча библиотек и лямды в java 8 есть (точно можно подобную ерунду и в java написать в строку).

Comment: > И как без LINQ написать вот такой однострочник:

@VladD, так в Java для выразительной работы с коллекциями же Stream API сделали.

Comment: @Nofate: Я с ним не очень знаком — покажете пример кода, выполняющего ту же задачу? Я не покритиковать, а из реального любопытства. (Мой пример читает файл построчно и записывает в целевой файл только строки, не начинающиеся с `#`.)

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov: google "Java Equivalent async/await", [первая ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16539332/276994):

> No, there isn't any equivalent of async/await in Java - or even in C# before v5.
>
> It's a fairly complex language feature to build a state machine behind the scenes.

Comment: @VladD,

    Files.write(
        Paths.get("filtered.txt"),
        Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")).filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#")).collect(Collectors.<String>toList()),
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW
    );

на Java это чуток длинней и "enterprisy", но это можно решить утильным методом, и будет что-то вроде:

    FileUtils.write("filtered.txt",
        FilesUtils.lines("input.txt").filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#")).collect(Collectors.<String>toList()));

Comment: @Nofate: Спасибо! Симпатично получается.

Но мне кажется, что это немного не то: `.collect(Collectors.<String>toList())` _материализует_ последовательность, т. е., превращает её в реальный, потенциально огромный контейнер в памяти. Поскольку `Files.write` принимает `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`, может, он проглотит stream?

Comment: @VladD, как я понял из лекции в Оракле, стримы сами по себе не являются ни проекцией, ни контейнером. Они просто в builder-стиле выстраивают модель конвейера, который будет как-то обработан при вызове `reduce` или `collect`.

 Причем там целый дивный мир с планировщиками и оптимизаторами, которые решают, что с этим конвейером делать с учетом сортировок, упорядоченности, параллелизма, иммутабельности и нуллабельности.

Comment: @Nofate: Угу. Но представьте себе, что файл размером больше оперативки. Не хотелось бы получить переполнение памяти, когда то же самое с явным циклом прошло бы без проблем.

То есть по сути нам нужен терминальный элемент stream'а (коллектор?), который соберёт строки не в память, а в файл. Есть такой?

(.NET-овский `File.WriteAllLines` — именно такой коллектор.)

Comment: @VladD, еще там добавили ленивые бесконечные стримы, так что, чтобы не материализовывать ничего, можно просто использовать forEach:

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\work\\input.txt"))
             .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#"))
             .forEach(Main::write);
    }
    
    public static void write(String s) {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("c:\\work\\filtered.txt"), s.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
        } catch (IOException e) {} // да, беда forEach не способен пробросить исключение в вызывающий метод
    }

Comment: > То есть по сути нам нужен терминальный элемент stream'а (коллектор?), который соберёт строки не в память, а в файл. Есть такой?

Из коробки, может, и нет, но не возбраняется написать свой коллектор (это просто класс, возвращающий параметры для обычного reduce: аккумулятор, операцию, инициализатор). Хотя для сайд-эффектов как раз и задуман `forEach`.

P.S. Бесконечные стримы с forEach, разумеется, не связаны. Видно, спать пора.

Comment: @Nofate: О, это то, что надо! А можно написать кастомный `forEach`? На .NET кастомные коллекторы пишутся довольно просто:

    public static DumpToFile(this IEnumerable<string> stream, string filename)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        using (var iterator = stream.GetIterator())
        {
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
                writer.WriteLine(iterator.Current)
        }
    }

    // ...
    File.ReadAllLines(...).Where(...).DumpToFile("out.txt");

Comment: @Nofate: А, пока я писал, вы уже ответили :)

Comment: @VladD, ну я покумекал тут, вышло так:

    public static Collector<String, Void, Void> dumpToFile(Path path) {
        return Collector.of(
                () -> null, 
                (a, s) -> { try{ Files.write(path, (s + "\n").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND); } catch (IOException e) {} },
                (a, b) -> null, 
                new Collector.Characteristics[0]);
    }

    ...

    Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\work\\input.txt"))
         .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#"))
         .collect(dumpToFile(Paths.get("c:\\work\\filtered.txt")));

Можно еще по пути байты посчитать )

Comment: @Nofate: Раз пошла такая пьянка... А можно так, чтобы не переоткрывать файл для записи каждой строки? Производительность же страдает...

Comment: @VladD, само собой можно, использовать в качестве аккумулятора не null, а какой-нибудь Writer.

Answer (score 6):

#### Вкратце

**C# сильнее как язык:** в Java нет практически ничего, чего нет в C#. Как язык, Java отстал от времени и находится в роли догоняющего. Новые возможности натыкаются на несметное число проблем, унаследованных из-за обратной совместимости. Одна из критических проблем — type erasure.

**Java сильнее как платформа:** для C# нет такого количества библиотек, как для Java. Java гораздо популярнее в опен-сорсе. Разрабатывая более-менее популярные вещи, вы никогда не заметите разницу, но если закапываться в экзотику, то разница весьма ощутима.

Раньше C# был относительно закрытым проектом, теперь он со всех сторон открытый, однако поезд ушёл, поэтому разрыв в размере опенсорсного сообщества не сократится никогда. В свою очередь Java как язык тоже уже ничто не может спасти, ибо обратная совместимость — святая корова.

Если перед вами стоит выбор "C# или Java", то всё просто:

- Хотите получать удовольствие от красивого кода — изучайте C#.
- Хотите более мощное опенсорсное сообщество — изучайте Java и переходите на Kotlin.

#### Про фичи

Достаточно поглядеть [Comparison of C# and Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java), чтобы понять пропасть между языками. Не верьте тем, кто говорит, что Джава сильна минимализмом — они врут (или просто привыкли писать огромные конструкции, когда достаточно одной строчки).

Приведённые в первом посте фичи — это или обман, или незнание, или манипуляция.

- "Легковесные классы" никто не использует со времён появления лямбд. Это был корявый нечитаемый костыль для обхода проблемы. Где-то они остались как царское наследие, но в новом коде их быть не должно.
- Нестатические внутренние классы — это просто классы со ссылкой владельца, проблема решается в две строки кода. Это очень минимальный синтаксический сахар.
- Проверяемые исплючения — источник огромного количества проблем, который корректно работает только на красивых примерах в десять строчек. В реальности же возникают проблемы с версионностью, наследованием, типами для лямбд и прочим.
- Final параметры не нужны, так как это всего лишь огрызок константности из C++, а при отсутствии всей системы вокруг это бессмысленная декорация.
- Информация про catch устарела. Теперь там можно городить что угодно с паттерн-матчингом.
- Аналогично с default interface implementation — эту фичу уже добавили.

*Полный* список *важных* фич, которые отсутствуют в C#, но есть в Java:

- Strict floating point: детерминированные вычисления над числами с плавающей точкой. Можно получить костыльным способом, зависящим от ОС.
- Soft, phantom ссылки. Польза спорная, потому что, скорее всего, кэш вы будете городить ручками, а не надеяться на невнятную магию.
- Возможность запустить на большем количестве устройств. Холодильник скорее будет поддерживать джаву, андроид нативно поддерживает джаву.
- Более гибкая настройка рантайма: зоопарк сборщиков мусора, вот это всё.

В общем-то, всё. Если же перечислять то, что есть в C#, но нет в Java, то список получится непомерно длинным.

Разумеется, даже в условиях серьёзного отставания джавы джависты не хотят предавать платформу. Определённое распространение получили альтернативные языки на JVM, например, Kotlin и Scala. В чём-то они мощнее C#, но по популярности они сильно уступают обоим языкам, и у них свои проблемы. У Kotlin наиболее серьёзные шансы, потому что он получил официальную поддержку от Google на Android.

#### Итог

По популярности в энтерпрайзе языки примерно на одном уровне. Детали зависят от области разработки и страны проживания.

Если вы хотите получать удовольствие от программирования, выбирайте C#. Если для вас критичен более широкий выбор редких библиотек, то выбирайте Java, но по возможности переходите на Kotlin. Если же вы хотите покопаться во всём, то морально готовьтесь к тому, что вам ну никак не обойти ещё несколько языков типа JavaScript (весь веб до сих пор на нём, не имеет отношения к Java), Python (один из самых популярных языков для связки инструментария) и прочих.

Comment: Phantom ссылки в Java играют ту же самую роль, что и SafeHandle в .net, хотя возможности у них разные. Так что я бы не назвал их пользу спорной.

Answer (score 2):

Сила, брат, в простоте. Мощь Java как раз и кроется в простоте. Есть такой принцип [Бритва Оккама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0) - проще говоря:

> Не умножай сущностей без необходимости

Все эти linq, attributes - без них спокойно можно прожить.

Например, в C# есть такое понятие, как `partial` - так это вообще преступление и оксюморон!

Comment: @Barmaley: Зря вы так на `partial`. Прекрасное средство, если у вас в проекте есть кодогенерация. Генератор производит `partial`-часть, а вы руками дописываете недостающее. Без этого приходилось бы делать вставки кода в директивах кодогенератора, что ужасно с точки зрения отладки и поддержки.

Comment: Да я верю в то, что это где-то необходимо, но согласитесь, это же разрушает целостность кода - получается, что один класс может быть разбит на несколько частей.

Comment: @Barmaley: Вы, конечно, правы, но по крайней мере все эти места явно обозначены, так что на мой вкус потери невелики.

Comment: @VladD: partial-классы плохи тем, что вызывают один из редких случаев undefined behaviour в C#-е, т.к. не указан порядок инициализации статических полей, и если они используют для инициализации значения полей из части класса, лежащей в другом файле, может выйти... не совсем ожидаемый результат =)

Comment: @Mints97: А почему UB? В терминологии C++ это unspecified behaviour (т. к. само по себе не может привести к например вылету программы). Однако же, в подавляющем большинстве случаев точный порядок инициализации неважен, поэтому выигрыш от использования partial там, где это нужно, намного превосходит потери.

Comment: @Mints97: Обычно разные части partial-класса независимы (одна генерируется автоматически, другая пишется вручную), так что ситуация довольно редка. Но конечно это в некотором смысле неожиданность и нерегулярность языка. Впрочем, если выбирать, я лично согласен на нерегулярный partial по сравнению с его отсутствием.

Answer (score 2):

Из того, что еще не было упомянуто: по-разному устроены способы реализации ко- и контра- вариантности в generics-ах.

### Как оно работает в C#

В шарпах, как известно, например, ковариантный интерфейс можно объявить вот так (пример нагло сворован с MSDN):

```
interface ICovariant<out R>
{
    R GetSomething();
}
```

Тогда, если у нас есть класс по типу:

```
class Implementation<T> : ICovariant<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetSomething()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

И два наследующих друг от друга класса:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
```

Мы можем сделать так:

```
Implementation<B> b = new Implementation<B>();
ICovariant<A> a = b;
```

Т.е. получается, что `ICovariant<B>` как будто наследует от `ICovariant<A>`. Аналогично с контравариантностью, только там у type paramet-ра модификатор `in` вместо `out`, и все ровно наоборот - созданный от базового класса (`A`) экземпляр как бы "наследует" от производного (`B`). (на самом деле, это не наследование, а отношение is-a, т.е. если `B` есть `A`, то `ICovariant<B>` есть `ICovariant<A>`, но это уже семантические дебри).

### Как оно работает в Java

А в Джаве по те же цели запилили другой механизм, который иногда ругают за ограниченность и меньшую безопасность, однако работает же!

Если я ничего не путаю, это называется call-site co/contra- variance. Фокус тут в том, что в шарпах вариантность (ко-, контра-, ин-) задается в декларации интерфейсов и делегатов, а у Джавы - в декларации самих объектов.

Это пашет через Джавины wildcard-ы (когда вместо `T` в "клювиках" стоит `?`). Аналогичный данному для шарпов пример тут будет выглядеть так:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    public T field;
}

class A {}
class B extends A {}

GenericClass<B> b = new GenericClass<B>();
GenericClass<? extends A> a = b;
```

`?` (Wildcard) в качетсве type-paramet-ра обозначает, что черт его, собственно, знает, что это за тип такой, так что расслабиться с проверкой типов чуток можно.

Они бывают unbounded (просто один ? в клювиках), upper-bounded (`<? extends A>`, т.е. об этом типе есть информация, что он наследует от какого-то другого типа - `A`. По сути, `<? extends Object>` аналогично unbounded wildcard), и lower-bounded (`<? super B>`, т.е. этот тип должен быть одним из предков другого типа - `B`).

Upper-bounded wildcards используются, как я продемонстрировал выше, для ковариантности, а lower-bounded wildcards, как ясно, для контравариантности.

Вообще и wildcard-ы, и механизмы ко- и контра- вариантности в шарпах - тема большая и довольно интересная, рекомендую почитать по ним поподробнее (особенно про обход безопасности типов при помощи wildcard-ов, пример [тут](http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=14)).